# How do I fix an arrayindexoutofboundsexception error?

Tags: java, arrays

**this is the code I am dealing with**

```
public class NameTag
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println ();
        System.out.println ("   " + args[0]);
        System.out.println ("My name is " + args[1]);
        System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

**this is the error that keeps showing each time I try to run the program**
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at NameTag.main(NameTag.java:6)

**I am using BlueJ Version 3.1.0**
**I have no idea how to fix this error, I have tried many different things but nothing is working. Please help.**

Comment: You need to pass some arguments (at least 2 with your code) when running your main method.

Comment: are you aware what the purpose of the `args` array is and are you doing what needs to be done to fill it when you run the program?

Comment: You need to run the program with at least two arguments on the command line.  I'm not familiar with BlueJ so I don't know how to run programs and pass arguments.

Answer (score 2):

That means you haven't passed any arguments to the program at execution. Therefore, accessing `args[0]` and `args[1]` leads to the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. http://www.bluej.org/help/archive.html#tip9 explains how to pass command line arguments to BlueJ. To save you the trouble of following the link, pass the following parameter to main:

```
{ "foo", "bar" }
```

to have the String "foo" in `args[0]` and "bar" in `args[1]`. Also, it's good practice to check the length of the `args` array before doing anything with it, to make sure that arguments have indeed been passed.

Answer (score 1):

Check for the length of the array before doing any other operations.

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    if(args.length > 1) {
       System.out.println ();
       System.out.println ("   " + args[0]);
       System.out.println ("My name is " + args[1]);
       System.out.println ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On blueJ, when you run, make sure you enter your input in the correct way and not empty. It will take your input and evaluate args[0] and args[1] from the input. It throws the exception when it can't find any argument.